# Facebook Open Graph configure actions

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

On the past/present tense preview box it's always showing: action is + 'a' + object
ie. user name is cooking **a** recipe
on the tutorial it is shown as  user name is cooking {object_title} on ...

How do I remove the 'a' and make is looks like in {object_title} example?

Answer (score 0):

That is shown differently at different times.
The short version (in the Ticker) is usually shown as "User is cooking Eggs".
In aggregations or detailed views the longer version might be "User is cooking a recipe: Eggs".

You don't have to do anything special to make this work.